# GNU Emacs-23.3.1 won't load CEDET-1.0

Tags: emacs, cedet

I've just updated my emacs and recompliled in byte-code some of its extensions. I also have updated some packages like subversion via emacs-updater, as is suggested to me after update.
But now i got

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: cedet-menu-map
```

There is more fun: if we cut the line loading cedet.el, ECB says

```
    error: ECB 2.40 - Error: ECB can only be used with 
cedet [1.0pre6, 1.0.9]! Please install it and restart Emacs!
```

Is there CEDET-1.0.9 anywhere? If it is, where it is?

OS: Gentoo

**upd:**

The use of packages **app-emacs/ecb** and **app-emacs/cedet** solved the problem.

Comment: Where did you get these packages from?

Answer (score 4):

Just change the version of CEDET in

```
<cedet_dir>/common/cedet.el
```

to 1.0.9

Answer (score 3):

Solved this by changing these lines in `ecb-upgrade.el`

from

```
(defconst ecb-required-cedet-version-min '(1 0 2 6)) 
(defconst ecb-required-cedet-version-max '(1 0 4 9))
```

to

```
(defconst ecb-required-cedet-version-min '(1 0 2 6))
(defconst ecb-required-cedet-version-max '(1 1 4 9))
```

from comments (pasted below) in code this fix seems to be a good one

> Convert the version-str VER-STR to the internal version-list format with
>   the following elements of the version-list:
>   1. Major-version
>   2. Minor-version
>   3. 0 = alpha, 1 = beta, 2 = pre, 3 = nothing (e.g. \"1.4\"), 4 = . (e.g. \"1.4.3\"
>   4. Subversion after the alpha, beta, pre or .

Answer (score 0):

It seems ECB is currently unmaintained or in hiatus. In any case, it doesn't work with newer CEDET versions. A CEDET version 1.0.9 does not exist.

Regarding your problem with loading CEDET with Emacs 23.3, the development version from CEDET should work fine:

http://cedet.sourceforge.net/bzr-repo.shtml

Comment: Still no luck. `File error: Cannot open load file, semantic-loaddefs` But semantic wasn't ever used or loaded yet.

Comment: It seems CEDET wasn't compiled correctly. I think the CEDET mailing-list would be a better place to get help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CEDET 1.06pre6.

As an example, you can see my configuration here: https://github.com/vikasmenon/emacs

Answer (score 0):

I have fixes for ECB + fresh CEDET, including CEDET included into Emacs. You can find more in [following blog post](http://alexott.blogspot.de/2012/06/ecb-fresh-emacscedet.html) (install manually from github), or you can install package from MELPA.